# .Net c# Generic issue

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

Here is an example :

```
public class B<T> {}
public class D : B<int> {}
public class A<T, S> where T : B<S> {}
public class C : A<D, int> {}

public class Test1
{
    public class test1
    {
        A<D, int> t = new C();
    }
}
```

What I would like do to is in declaring class C, only say : `C : A<D>`. Why I need to repeat int ? Because int is already a part of D.

Same in the test1 method. I would like to write : `A<D> t = new C()`;

How, can I achieve that ?

## UPDATE

Here with more realistic class names :

```
public class MyModel<T> { }
public class MyTrueModel : MyModel<int> { }

public class MyManager<T,S> where T : MyModel<S> { }
public class MyTrueManager : MyManager<MyTrueModel, int> { }

public class Test1
{
    public class test1
    {
        MyManager<MyTrueModel, int> t = new MyManager<MyTrueModel, int>();
    }
}
```

All the problem come from the class MyManager. If I was able to do something like : `MyManager<T> where T : MyModel` it'd would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
public class B<T> {}
public class D : B<int> {}
public class A<T, S> where T : B<S> {}
public class C : A<D, int> {}
public class Test1 {
    public class test1 {
        A<D, int> t = new C();
    }
}
```

Here's equivalent code:

```
public class B<T> {}
public class D : B<int> {}
public class A<U, V> where U : B<V> {}
public class C : A<D, int> {}
public class Test1 {
    public class test1 {
        A<D, int> t = new C();
    }
}
```

The point is that the `U` in `A<U, V>` is a dummy. When you replace `U` with `T` (and `V` with `S`) and write `A<T, S>` the `T` does not refer to the same `T` in `B<T>`. This is why you must use `C : A<D, int>`. If you were to only write `A<D>` the compiler does not know (and nor should it; see my comment below on free versus unbound variables) that you want to use `int` for `T` in `B<T>`.

> All the problem come from the class MyManager. If I was able to do something like `: MyManager<T>` where `T : MyModel` it's would be great.

This is not possible. `MyModel` is not declared as a type. Only `MyModel<T>` is a type. More specifically, it is an unbounded generic type. When you specify a type argument (e.g., `MyModel<int>`) then it will be a constructed type.

At this risk of confusing you further (on this admittedly confusing issue), it might help you read about [free and unbounded variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables).

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. It's help me to understand. Do you know if there's some workaround I can do to achieve what I want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably I missunderstood your question. But if you do not need int. Just use D.

```
public class B<T> { }
public class D : B<int> { }
public class A<T> where T : D { }
public class C : A<D> { }
public class Test1 { public class test1 { A<D> t = new C();    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

`A<D> t = new C();` won't work because you have previously declared A to require two generic parameters.

You could declare something like:

```
class A2<T> : A<T, int> {}
```

Then (I think) you could achieve `A2<D> t = new C();`, but I'm assuming that the compiler is smart enough to realize that A2 is compatible with C ... it may not be.

Is this an experiment? Looks like you might have trouble figuring out what this is supposed to do 6 months from now (or even 2 months from now :)

Comment: `A2<D> t2 = (A2<D>) ((A<D, int>) new C());` seems to work with A2 defined as above, but it's certainly not better :P

Answer (score -1):

Declare A as:

```
public class A<T> where T : B<S>
```

*Should* work, but I don't have a compiler on me so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I don't think this will compile: the compiler has no way to resolve S.

Comment: @Anon. No. If this were legal then I could say `A<int> a = new A<int>();` But now what binds `S`?

Comment: ...unless I am grossly mistaken, `int` does not inherit from `B(S)`.

Comment: But how can the compiler know that? It doesn't even know what `S` is. Don't use `int` if that will satisfy you. Here: `interface IDoNothing<U> { }`, `class A<T> where T : IDoNothing<U> { }` (what is `U`?) and `class C : IDoNothing<short>, IDoNothing<int>`. Finally, `A<C> a = new A<C>`. Well, `C` implements both `IDoNothing<short>` and `IDoNothing<int>` so which type (`short` or `int`) do we use for the unbound type variable `U`?

Comment: Things get funky when we start talking about conflicting interfaces no matter which way you slice it. Suppose two interfaces define methods that are identical except for their return type - what return type should the implementor provide?

Comment: @Anon.: In that case one of the interfaces will have to be implemented explicitly.